# How to compute derivative of exponent with power? [solved]

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, machine-learning

I was finding derivative of `p(x,w)` wrt `dw` given function below,

$$ P( y=1 \; \big| \; x, \, w) = \dfrac{1}{1 + \exp(- \langle w. x \rangle)} $$

was able to compute some parts as
$$ P(y=1 \; \big| \; x,\,w) =  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \exp(-(w.x))}} *  d(\exp(-(w.x))$$

but stuck in $$\dfrac{d(\exp(-(w.x))}{d(w)}$$

I tried to solve it as but i think i am wrong
$$ -(w)\exp(-w.x) $$

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the second equation is supposed to be the derivative of the first equation? Normally, the notation for the derivative is something like $f^{'}$ ... In this case, maybe $P'(x)$ could do?

Comment: And actually, the last result looks correct. Indeed the derivative
$$
\frac{d}{dx}e^{kx} = k e^{kx}
$$
due to the chain rule. In your case $k=-w$.

Comment: yes i've solved it, thanks. :)